# Prove number of prime factors $p$ in $n!$

Tags: number-theory

I am reading a book about number theory and there is one exercise say
If p is a prime number, the the number of factors of p in n! is

$\sum_{i>=1}\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{i}} \rfloor $

This is quite intuitive as each $p^{i}$ will contribute i to the total number of p in $n!$.

But I am not sure how to prove it rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

How many numbers less than $n$ are divisible by $p$?  $\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \rfloor$.  How many are divisible by $p$ twice?  $\lfloor \frac{n}{p^2} \rfloor$.  Keep going.

Comment: ya.. I know that. But Can I just say that? This is reasonable because let say $\lfloor \frac{20} {5} \rfloor$ $= 4$

Comment: Do I have to show anything else? like, do they overlap?(I know they don't)